# Difference between simplexml_load_file and simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I want to put a xml file into my programme and make it into an array so I can put it into a table.

I was wondering how I can do this and I have read the php manual, but I don't seem to be able to get to grips with it.

To do what I want, do I need to use `simplexml_load_string`, or do I need to command both of them(`simplexml_load_file` and `simplexml_load_string`), therefore load the xml file onto the programme, then turn it into a file.
Or does `simplesml_load_string` just does all of that for me.

Also I was wondering what `get_object_vars` does when you put it around an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each of the two functions returns `SimpleXMLElement` object, so you only need one of them depending on what you have to begin with, whether you have path to an XML file or content of the XML it self in a string variable, etc.

Notice in the documentation page, that [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) expects the `string` parameter to *contain the actual XML content*, while [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) expects the `string` parameter to *contain path to the XML file*.

Comment: Could you tell me which one I should use for this website?

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki since you have path/url to the XML file, try using `simplexml_load_file()`